# Team Build Error: Expression of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild

I am getting an error as soon as I’m triggering the build. 
We are using ***TFS2012 and VS2012***.

Actually I have customized the **DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml** to suite project requirement. 
And after adding the Custom Activities and Template we are getting an error..

**TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \ALM\VersioningBuild: Exception Message: Expression of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings' cannot be used for return type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.BuildSettings' (type ArgumentException)Exception Stack Trace:**

at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters)   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.LambdaTDelegate   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.LambdaTDelegate   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicHelper.CompileT   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicHelper.CompileT   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicHelper.CompileT   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.VisualBasicValue`1.CacheMetadata(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)   at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.OnInternalCacheMetadataExceptResult(Boolean createEmptyBindings)   at System.Activities.Activity`1.OnInternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings)   at System.Activities.Activity.InternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings, IList`1& validationErrors)   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivity(ChildActivity childActivity, ChildActivity& nextActivity, Stack`1& activitiesRemaining, ActivityCallStack parentChain, IList`1& validationErrors, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback)   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivityTreeCore(ChildActivity currentActivity, ActivityCallStack parentChain, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.CacheRootMetadata(Activity activity, LocationReferenceEnvironment hostEnvironment, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)   at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.InternalActivityValidationServices.InternalValidate()   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers.ValidateWorkflow(Activity activity, ValidationSettings validationSettings)   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildProcessCache.LoadFromXaml(String workflowXaml, TextExpressionImports textExpressionImports)   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)

I’m totally stuck over here.

Any help would be much appreaciated.Thanks!!

Comment: I had the same issue but this answer solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24177482/1016183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turn out that i was referring wrong version (Lower Version) of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow in my project.

but the Build server were having higher vresion of dll.